# AngularJS: How to bind ng-model to an 2 dimensional array

Tags: angularjs, html, multidimensional-array, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I am newbie in AngularJs.

I would like to create multidimensional array element in `ng-model` as defined below.

```
<Ojbect>
    <Array>
        <Element1>
            <var1>
            <var2>
        <Element2>
            <var1>
            <var2
```

I tried with following code.

```
ng-model="name.firstname.$index"

ng-model="name.firstname.[$index]"
```

But not getting any idea.

Please help ?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may use {{myModel.nestedProperty.arrayField[2]}} in a binging expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You should define it as `scope variable` in your controller.

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.parent = { child : {}};
```

**HTML**

```
<ANY ng-repeat="i in items">
  <span ng-model="parent.child[$index].firstname"></span>
  <span ng-model="parent.child[$index].lastname"></span>
</ANY>
```

For nested `ng-repeat`, use `$parent.$index`

```
<ANY ng-repeat="i in items">
   <ANY ng-repeat="val in i.dummy">
      <span ng-model="parent.child[$parent.$index][$index].firstname"></span>
      <span ng-model="parent.child[$parent.$index][$index].lastname"></span>
   </ANY>
</ANY>
```

FYI, This is just an example of code, not a real code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Array>
    <Element1>
        <var1>
        <var2>
    <Element1>
    </Element2>
        <var1>
        <var2>
    </Element2>
</Array>
```

In reference to this modelling you had in your question I came up with the following fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/nealhamilton/p355q5vw/